# Display Images in Datagrid view

Tags: c#

I have a C# form with `DataGridView`.
My question is how to display images in `DataGridView` from MySql database. Images are stored as BLOB.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you have with that? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this part of code

```
        MySqlDataReader myRead;
        myRead = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        ...
        byte[] img = (byte[])(myRead["picture_column"]);
        if (img == null)
            yourImage.ImageUrl = null;
        else {
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(img);
            yourImage.ImageURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String(img);
        ....
```